Create a Custom Attribute or Class for Swagger Documentation
I was wondering is there any way to create a custom class or attribute which I can call and keep all swagger documentation attributes at one place, for example This is my original code
 [HttpGet]
 [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "Get the list of customers",
        Description = "This Api returns the list of customers from database and and display on Customer Screen",
        Tags = ["Customer"]
    )
]
[SwaggerResponse(200, description: "Returns a list of customers if the request was successful.")]
[SwaggerResponse(500, "Internal Server Error along with the complete Error message.")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCustomersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Code to Get the customers
    return Ok(customers);
}

Is there any way to reduce all this code and create a custom attribute class and pass the values, something like this
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
public class SwaggerDocumentation : Attribute
{
    public SwaggerDocumentation(string operationSummary, string operationDescription, List<string> operationTags, string responseSuccessMessage)
    {
      // I am not sure what will come here, but ideally this is how it should look like
      [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = operationSummary,
        Description = operationDescription,
        Tags = operationTags)]

      [SwaggerResponse(200, description: $"Returns a {responseSuccessMessage} if the request was successful.")]
      [SwaggerResponse(500, "Internal Server Error along with the complete Error message.")]
    }  
}

and then decorate my function with something like
 [HttpGet]
 [SwaggerDocumentation("MySummary","MyDescription", "MyTags", "List of Customers")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetCustomersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {

 }

I am not sure even this possible.

The documentation is generated by the XML documentation of each method. To generate the documentation files you need to  enable it in the csproj file.

@PanagiotisKanavos, My Documentation is generating fine by first method, I just need to simplify the process and don't want to write same lines again and again in all methods.

You could create an operation filter that understands your custom attribute, and populates the documentation from there.

You can't just combine attributes like this either. Swagger/OpenAPI isn't just documentation, it specifies the schema of an API, something other tools can take and generate clients and DTOs without knowing how the actual service works. The actual schema is the Swagger JSON document, not the attributes. Tools like NSwag, Swashbuckle etc generate the document using their attributes. You'd have to customize eg SwashBuckle or whatever tool you use to understand your own attributes.

Swashbuckle allows customization and there are several extensions already. I'm not sure it's worth it in this case, just to save a few keystrokes. This isn't really simplifying anything. What would help instead would be to return the actual DTO instead of ActionResult, allowing Swashbuckle to document the response DTO as well

I am posting the answer here for anyone's else benefit.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SwaggerDocumentationAttribute(string summary, string description, string[] tags, string responseSuccessMessage) : Attribute
{
    public string Summary { get; } = summary;
    public string Description { get; } = description;
    public string[] Tags { get; } = tags;
    public string ResponseSuccessMessage { get; } = responseSuccessMessage;
}

and then I created another class to derive from IOperationFilter, Thanks to @Martin Costello for the idea.
public class SwaggerDocumentationOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
     public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
     {
         if (context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SwaggerDocumentationAttribute), false)?.FirstOrDefault() is
             not SwaggerDocumentationAttribute descriptionAttribute) 
          return;
    
       var tags = descriptionAttribute.Tags.Select(tagName => new OpenApiTag { Name = tagName }).ToList();
       operation.Summary = descriptionAttribute.Summary;
       operation.Description = descriptionAttribute.Description;
       operation.Tags = tags;

       // Remove the default 200 response, which was added by default by Swashbuckle
       operation.Responses.Remove("200");
        
       operation.Responses.Add("200", new OpenApiResponse { Description = $"Returns a {descriptionAttribute.ResponseSuccessMessage}, if operation was successful." });
       operation.Responses.Add("500", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Internal Server Error along with the complete Error message." });
     }
}

In my AddSwaggerGen, I had to add this filter
   c.OperationFilter<SwaggerDocumentationOperationFilter>();

and in the end, I called it like this
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerDocumentation("MySummary","MyDescription",["Customer"],"List of Customers")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCustomersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

}

